# Duda acerca del uso de las expresiones en programacion

Tags: javascript, algoritmos

Tengo entendido que las expresiones en los lenguajes de programacion devuelven un valor cuando resuelven un calculo. se puede usar en variables para asignarles un valor y también se pueden usar para pasarse como argumentos a una función luego de que se calculan.

Para plantear mi duda expondré este ejemplo (Estoy aprendiendo JavaScript)

```js
function calcularSuma(num1,num2){
  return num1 + num2;
}

let resultadoSuma = calcularSuma(1,2)
console.log(resultadoSuma)
```

Hago un return num1 + num2 sin asignar esos valores a alguna variable porque return aparte de devolver el control al programa, nos permite devolver un valor

¿Esto quiere decir que yo puedo usar una expresión (Construida a partir de valores y operadores) en donde sea que yo requiera asignar un valor como tal (En cualquier instrucción que requiera esto como asignar argumentos,asignar valores a variables o retornar un valor de una función) solo que en este caso en vez de asignar un valor directamente como 8 o "Juan" lo estoy calculando y puedo calcularlo porque los lenguajes permiten asignar valores realizando operaciones que se resuelven en un valor siempre y cuando las operaciones estén construidas debidamente con operadores y tipos de datos validos por el lenguaje?

Comment: Eso es totalmente válido en Javascript así como en muchos otros lenguajes. De hecho estás pisando un terreno llamado [**Programación Funcional**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_funcional). En dicho paradigma de programación (el cual no es nuevo), se hace el énfasis en que los cambios en los datos de cualquier programa deben expresarse mediante funciones (a través del tiempo), dando así como resultado que el concepto de *variables* (depósito o almacén de datos) no esté permitido, y por ende tampoco las operaciones de asignación o actualización sobre las mismas. Saludos